# Running the same JUnit tests for multiple classes using @ParameterizedTest with either @MethodSource or @ValueSource

Tags: java, generics, junit, reflection, junit5

I am creating a library of sorting algorithms. Each class has the same method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] array)
```

I would have the classes all implement an interface or extend an
abstract class but the `sort` method is `static` which means it can't
be overridden.

This is my first time using JUnit 5. I would like to run the same
JUnit tests on all of the sort classes. After some research, it seems
the way to do this in JUnit 5 is using `@ParameterizedTest`. The way I
was considering is to get the class as a parameter in the test method,
get the `sort` method using reflection, and invoke it. The issue is, I
seem to be having an issue passing the classes to the tests. When I
use `@ParameterizedTest` with either `@ValueSource` or
`@MethodSource`, the `Class` in the parameter is of type
`java.lang.Class`.

Just to test the use of `@ParameterizedTest`, I have tried the following:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("sortClasses")
public void simpleParameterizedTest(Class<?> sortClass) {
   System.out.println(sortClass.getClass().getName());
}

private static Class<?>[] sortClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {
        BubbleSort.class
    };
}
```

and

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = {BubbleSort.class})
public void simpleParameterizedTest(Class<?> sortClass) {
    System.out.println(sortClass.getClass().getName());
}
```

Both print: `java.lang.Class` instead of `my.package.BubbleSort`.

I haven't tried it yet but I know I can get the classes using
reflection with the `String` names of the classes but that seems like
wild overkill.

What am I missing? Is this the best approach for this in JUnit 5?

Comment: You're calling `sortClass.getClass().getName()`.  `getClass` is an integral method of every `Object`.  Your `Object` is an instance of `Class`, so it's `getClass` will return `Class`.  What does simply calling `sortClass.getName()` give?

Comment: @user2478398 I feel like an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the solving comment to an answer:

`getClass()` is a method which comes on all java `Object`s to tell you the `class` of that `Object`.  Since your `sortClass` `Object` *is itself* a `Class` `Object`, calling `getClass()` on it results in `Class`.  Instead, you can simply call `sortClass.getName()`, which *will* provide you the name of the `sortClass` itself.

---

TL;DR:

Replace `sortClass.getClass().getName()` with `sortClass.getName()`. :)

Comment: Was beating my head with this. It's always the simple things... Thanks

Comment: The other day I lost 1.5 hours tracking _all_ the ways a method could be called to investigate a defect...  I forgot I had gotten to that method via a stack trace which told me _exactly_ which way it was called...  We all have those moments :P